# Example of a fundamental polygon

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, non-orientable-surfaces

I was studying some Topology and learned to the concept of fundamental polygons and their surface equivalences. Playing with some configurations I couldn't make sense of the following one.

[image: Mysterious fundamental polygon]

Gluing the blue ones first, I would get a Möbius strip, so I suppose that my surface is non-orientable (by the way, is that true? If parallel lines are glued in opposing directions, my surface will be non-orientable independently of the rest?).

I know that compact non-orientable manifolds are classified in terms of connected sums of projective planes. So what would it be this one?

Comment: are the black edges glued or not?

Comment: They are not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As drawn, the quotient is homeomorphic to a surface with a single boundary component. To see this, lets first glue the two red edges together.

[image: gluing]

Notice the endpoints of the two black segments get glued together when you quotient by the blue. Hence they form a single circle.

Now, you pointed out, the surface has to be non orientable. So to figure out what surface it is, we only need to compute the Euler characteristic. From your picture, we can give the surface a cell structure with 2 vertices, 4 edges, and 1 face. So $\chi = 2 - 4 +1 = -1$. So the surface has to be $\mathbb{R}P^2 \# \mathbb{R}P^2 \smallsetminus \text{2-cell}$.

[image]

EDIT: I'll explain why this is $\mathbb{R}P^2 \# \mathbb{R}P^2 \smallsetminus \text{2-cell}$.

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $\Sigma$ be a closed surface (so compact with no boundary). If $\Sigma$ is orientable, then $\chi(\Sigma) = 2 - 2g$ and $\Sigma \simeq S^2$ if $g=0$ and $\Sigma \simeq \#_{g} S^1\times S^1$. If $\Sigma$ is nonorientable, then $\chi(\Sigma) = 2-k$ and $\Sigma\simeq \#_k \mathbb{R}P^2$.

Now the surface depicted above has a single boundary component. So, if we attach a 2-cell to this boundary component, we will have a closed surface. Then we can apply the theorem. After attaching the 2-cell, we have 3 vertices, 4 edges, and 2 faces. Hence $\chi = 0$ and the classification theorem say it must be $\mathbb{R}P^2 \# \mathbb{R}P^2$. This is for the original surface PLUS an additional 2-cell. To figure out our surface, we simply remove the 2-cell we added.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. First of all, very nice diagrams. While I was waiting someone to answer, I found in wikipedia that "The Euler characteristic of a closed non-orientable surface can be calculated from its non-orientable genus k (the number of real projective planes in a connected sum decomposition of the surface) as

χ = 2 - k"

So it would be a RP2#RP2#RP2 surface. That formula is not applicable in this example?

Comment: And I didn't get why the answer would be a RP2#RP2∖2-cell.

Comment: It depends on if the black lines are glued or not, and how they are glued.

Comment: @Douglas I added some clarification regarding the Euler characteristic and the classification of surfaces.

Comment: I got it now, it wasn't closed before. Thank you sir.